# WkWebview Cannot load Blob data in <a href

Tags: ios, blob, wkwebview

I have a web application that uses the WkWebview and has offline data stored in an IndexedDB.  I am trying to load an offline PDF file from within the WkWebview using the following javascript.

```
var blob = b64toBlob(UserResource_data[i].PDF,'text/html'); //Stored as base 64 in indexeddb
    file = new Blob([blob], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    fileURL = webkitURL.createObjectURL(file);
    ResourceLink = '<a href="'+fileURL+'" download="'+UserResource_data[i].Filename+'" type="application/pdf" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="eye" data-mini="true" data-ajax="false" target="_blank">View PDF</a>';
```

However nothing loads in the webview I just get a white screen and nothing crashes.

Swift Code:

```
self.webView!.loadRequest(navigationAction.request)
```

I have implemented a method to handle links with _blank for the target and it works fine for loading external pdf files.

Is this supported by WkWebView? or does anyone have any better ideas.
Embedding these files within the project is not an option as they must be externally update-able

EDIT - Found Workaround

Instead of using "createObjectURL()" I created a data URL

```
function LoadOfflinePDF(id){
var blob = b64toBlob(UserResource_data[id].PDF,'text/html');
var reader = new FileReader();
var out = new Blob([blob], {type: 'application/pdf'});
reader.onload = function(e){
  //window.open(reader.result,'_blank');
  console.log("LoadedpdfURL: "+id);
  UserResource_data[id].PDF = reader.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(out);
```

}
Then created a popup with the dataURL

```
function openPDFReader(){
var id = this.id;
id = id.split("_");
id = id[1];
console.log("Opening: "+id);
window.open(UserResource_data[id].PDF);
```

}

So now I can properly display my offline PDF files stored in IndexedDB using the WKWebView

Comment: Hi @KleggerKoder have you got any lead to this yet?